# Google Cardboard - are there an iPhone / iOS starter projects for the Cardboard VR kit?

Tags: ios, iphone, augmented-reality, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I'm looking at the [Google Cardboard kit, an inexpensive VR setup](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/) that uses Android Devices to play 3d VR games. I see that they have an Android demo project, but **is there any iOS or Objective-C port of the Cardboard project?**

If not, are there any other VR projects for iOS that can be modified to work with the cardboard kit?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*June 2015 update*

Google has added iOS support to their official [Unity SDK](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/developers/). Even though the Unity plugin bundles a pre-compiled iOS Cardboard binary, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to use it in a standalone fashion.

---

I just completed an iOS CardboardSDK port for the company I'm working for.

It (mostly) has feature parity with Android's CardboardSDK v0.5.1. Works on iOS 7+. Tested on iPhone 6 and iPhone 5.

You can check it out here: [CardboardSDK-iOS](https://github.com/rsanchezsaez/cardboardsdk-ios).

Answer (score 7):

According to this [article](http://9to5mac.com/2014/08/22/makeshift-apple-vr-headset-how-to-use-google-cardboard-with-an-iphone-video/):

> Virtually any iOS app that was designed to work with the Durovis Dive
>   will work with Google Cardboard. There are only about five apps worth
>   checking out at this point, but as the demand rises I’m sure other
>   developers will jump on board and craft better VR experience apps. The
>   best way to find compatible apps at the moment is by searching for
>   “Durovis” or “Durovis Dive” on the App Store. Either of those terms
>   will pull up a variety of apps that were designed to work with VR
>   headsets.

Here's the Durovis SDK:
http://www.durovis.com/sdk.html